# Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added a jumbotron to my webpage, my page is now displaying the bottom and right scroll bar! Not sure how to resolve this.

Any tip's or pointers much appreciated.

url http://tyrescanner.net/contact-us

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">             
                                <div class="jumbotron">
                                    <h1><span style="color: #ffffff;">Welcome to Tyrescanner</span></h1>
                                      <p></p>
                                    <h2>Contact us.</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: have you tried with overflow:hidden; ?

Answer (score 1):

Your jumbotron is wrapped with divs `row` and `col-md-12`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">             
      <div class="jumbotron">
```

Delete them and leave only jumbotron.

or remove paddings from your css:

```
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    /* padding-left: 0px; */
    /* padding-right: 0px; */
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

It overwrites bootstrap css and cause problem with page width.

Answer (score 1):

what are you asking for? I assume you just don't want bottom scrollbar ,is that right?

If so, below is your CSS for HTML . change that as below it's in your bootstrap.css file and line number 1071

```
html {
 font-size: 10px;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: How do you format your code in stackoverflow!!! this is not working `text` = Code Formatting = text

Comment: @Tom, if its code than you have to give 4 space in front all new line. and it doesn't work in comment section only on reply. Did you solve the issue now?

Answer (score 1):

After viewing your site I see some issues:

1. You're using a container-fluid and a nested container-fluid as the jumbotron parent element, the nested one is redundant.
2. Then I see you've overridden container-fluid and .col--12 classes default bootstrap left/right padding to 0px but you didn't change the default margin of the .row class to have 0px left/right margin hence your bottom scroll bar.
3. For the footer, remove the margin-top and make the footer a direct child of the body element then add the following css to the form, body and html elements: `height:100%;`, the rest is margins that you added to the elements.

Comment: THis is my css for the footer, if I change the position to absolute, the footer overlaps the rest of the page `text`={!!#footer{ background-color: #000; color: white; position:relative; /*position: absolute;*/ margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 0px; /*height: 80px;*/ /*width:100%;*/ clear:both; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20%; bottom:0; } = text

Comment: See my updated answer footer the footer also I just inspected your site and it looks like your misusing bootstrap...
On most of the usage scenarios you should use .row and .col-* classes in containers. not doing so is a very bad practice. My Suggestion to you is to redo the bootstrap tutorial and perhaps do some css tutorials...